# CSV file to hash

Tags: ruby, csv

I want to take a simple 2-column CSV file and turn it to a Hash of initials as keys, full name as values. How would you do this?

```
csv_text = File.read('composer_initials.csv')

csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true)
```

I've tried:

```
csv.to_a.map {|row| ro.to_hash}
csv.map {|row| row.to_hash}
```

> SOLUTION:

This ended up doing the job:

```
composers = {}

CSV.foreach("composer_initials.csv") do |row|
  composers[row[0]] = row[1]
end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a Hash from a CSV-like file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419024/create-a-hash-from-a-csv-like-file)

Comment: I'm in the CL trying more things now, seems like it should be simple. I'll edit with other things I've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
hash = {}
csv= CSV.parse(csv_text)
csv.each do |row|
  hash[row[0]] = row[1]
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up doing something similar, I added it as an edit to my OP.